# how to query whereHas on a belongs to many relationship using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

hi i am having a `User` and `Task` model and they have a many to many relation ship like below i added :

```
 public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'user_tasks');
    }
```

and in my user model :

```
 public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }
```

and in my controller i want to get the task that are assigned to the logged in user like below :

```
   $task = Task::whereHas('users', function(Builder $query){
            $query->where('id',Auth::user()->id);
        })->get();
        dd($task);
```

but i get this error :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `tasks` where exists (select * from `users` inner join `user_tasks` on `users`.`id` = `user_tasks`.`user_id` where `tasks`.`id` = `user_tasks`.`task_id` and `id` = 4))
```

and when i change the `id` to `users.id` i get empty value but when i load it like below :

```
$task = Task::with('users')->get();
```

i get all the task with the relationships and they are working well but with whereHas its not working
thanks in advance

Comment: btw, if it is a `belongsToMany` it has to be `belongsToMany` on both sides

Comment: change `users.id` to `user_id` in the `where`

Comment: ye my fault it was user_id thanks for the answer feel free to answer it i accep ti

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are dealing with the pivot table with this relationship you can use the pivot table field `user_id` to filter:

```
$task = Task::whereHas('users', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

why not just:

```
$userTasks=Auth::user()->tasks;
```

this will get the current user tasks.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tasks.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `tasks` where `tasks`.`user_id` = 4 and `tasks`.`user_id` is not null)

Comment: a bit wierd i know that this should work but it returns error as i said

Comment: @Farshad because the relationship is wrong, it has to be `belongsToMany` not `hasMany`